# Get UUID from string in mssql (sql-server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-parsing

I get some field in mssql which contain uuid like:

```
root://Item/Item//4296d6c9-3cc4-3d21-af4f-0cd4cdfbf31b/15/11
```

And I need to retrieve UUID from such string. It can change, and be like

`root://Item/Item//4296d6c9-3cc4-3d21-af4f-0cd4cdfbf31b/15` or

`root://Item/Item//4296d6c9-3cc4-3d21-af4f-0cd4cdfbf31b`

I've tried to use same pattern as for pstgres, where it works, like:

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12})%', 'root://Item/Item//4296d6c9-3cc4-3d21-af4f-0cd4cdfbf31b/15/11');
```

But receive 0; It seems like some other regexp rules exists for mssql. How I should write pattern for UUID?

Comment: Maybe `SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, '/') WHERE TRY_CAST(value as uniqueidentifier) is not null`

Answer (score 0):

Currently I found a solution, but it looks a little weird:

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]-[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]-[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]-[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]-[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]%', 'root://SomeItem/Item/any/4296d6c9-3cc4-3d21-af4f-0cd4cdfbf31b/15/11') AS StartIndex;
```

Why mssql doesn't support {number of repeats}, or do I have to use some other syntax?

Comment: If your collation is case-insensitive, you can remove either the upper or lowercase variants of the same character. Not pretty but the wildcard expression can be shortened with `REPLICATE`: `SELECT PATINDEX('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9,a-f]', 8)+'-'+REPLICATE('[0-9,a-f]', 4)+'-'+REPLICATE('[0-9,a-f]', 4)+'-'+REPLICATE('[0-9,a-f]', 4)+'-'+REPLICATE('[0-9,a-f]', 12)+'%', 'root://SomeItem/Item/any/4296d6c9-3cc4-3d21-af4f-0cd4cdfbf31b/15/11') AS StartIndex;`

Comment: The LIKE support is very basic in mssql server out of the box, but one can create a CLR functions that uses regex

Comment: Thnks, @DanGuzman it works!) Can be little improved: ```PATINDEX('%' + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 8) + '-' + REPLICATE(REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 4) + '-', 3) + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 12) + '%', 'root://SomeItem/Item/any/4296d6c9-3cc4-3d21-af4f-0cd4cdfbf31b/15/11') as StartIndex```

Comment: @ValeriyK., yes, that will save some keystrokes.